# Javascript Converter in kgs and LBs

Tags: javascript, html

---

Javascript Implementation and Html form

Hi i created a code that would help me get the weight based on the information used in switch case  and the resultant would be available in Kgs or Pounds when either of the radio buttons are clicked.But in my case every time output is being displayed as NAN.Please guide me where i am making the mistake.

Also if you could guide me the best way .I would be grateful for the same
As i am new to javascript i would request to please guide me .Thanks

---

```
<form>
    HEIGHT:
    <input type=text name="height" id="wt1" onChange="convert(this.form);" onfocus="reset()" placeholder="feet" value="0" />Feet
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>&nbsp;
    <label>
        <br>WEIGHT IN Kg:
        <input name="weight" id="wt2" type="radio" onClick="convert(this.form);" class="wt" />Kg</label>
    <label>
        <br>WEIGHT IN Pounds:
        <input name="weight" id="wt3" onClick="convert(this.form);" type="radio" class="wt" />Lb</label>
    <label>
        <br>WEIGHT :
        <input name="weight34" type="text" id="wt4" placeholder="Kg/Lb" onfocus="reset()" />
    </label>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function convert(form) {
        var calweight1;
        var calweight2;
        var finalcalweight;
        var heightvalue;
        heightvalue = form.height.value;
        if (form.weight[0].checked) {
            switch (isNaN(parseInt(heightvalue))) {
            case 5.0:
                calweight1 = 50 + 2.3 + 5.0 + 1.9;
                break;
            case 5.1:
                calweight1 = 50 + 2.3 + 5.1 + 3.8;
                break;
            case 5.2:
                calweight1 = 50 + 2.3 + 5.2 + 5.4;
                break;
            }
            finalcalweight = Math.round(calweight1);
        } else if (form.weight[1].checked) {
            switch (isNaN(parseInt(heightvalue))) {
            case 5.0:
                calweight2 = 106.0 + 5.0;
                break;
            case 5.1:
                calweight2 = 5.1 + 112.0;
                break;
            case 5.2:
                calweight2 = 5.2 + 118.0;
                break;
            }
            finalcalweight = Math.round(calweight2);
        }
        form.weight34.value = finalcalweight;
    }
</script>
```

---

Comment: The first step might be to ignore the JavaScript altogether and fix the form so that it uses labels properly, isn't calling `onfocus="reset()"` during the process of someone trying to enter data, etc. Once the form is valid html then it is possible to add on behavior with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

By a quick look I can see you use `isNaN`. Note that it is a boolean function and returns true or false. So, actually, you are `swtich`ing `true` or `false` instead of the value. 
So, this indeed was the problem, here's the problem **[fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/hjQpH/1/)**.